# .net MVC3 DataAnnotation - how to prevent duplication of validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I am having issues with validation using data annotations and wondering if anyone has done something similar.

We have placed our domain entitities into a domain layer and for each domain entity we have a MetadataType class which contains the applicable business rules in the form of annotations. The domain entity class also implements IValidatableObject for any validations that not implemented using DataAnnotations.

In the Web/presentation layer we are using view model objects. These could be data from multiple domain entities or a single domain entity, for now lets presume a single domain entity. This model view is decorated with [MetadataType(typeof(DomainEntityMetaData))]

This keeps our business logic in the domain and out of the view models. However, the view model does not implement IValidatableObject and as such this is never executed. I obviously do not want to repeat the validation in the view.

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: sounds like you need an action filter to me.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share some code.I mean how your ViewModel and Entities are related? How the data flows, so that we can think how data can be validated

Answer (score 5):

Part of your problem here is that you're trying to carry through your domain validation into your view.  While that can work in some situations, it's really a violation of the Seperation of Concerns principle.  View and Domain are different concerns, and they each have their own validation concerns.

This is particularly a problem because your ViewModel objects are not identical to your domain model objects, yet you're trying to utilize domain metadata as the validator for your view model.  That's always going to cause problems.

for instance, you might have a wizard that steps through the creation of a domain object across multiple pages.  If you carry your domain validation through, you will have validation problems because you're not filling in required data in various steps.

Regardless of what domain validation you may have in place, you have to define your view validation.  This may mean duplicating metadata.

Seperation of concerns is often at war with DRY (don't repeat yourself).  If you want to prefer DRY over SOC then you will need to merge your domain models into your view models and use the same model for both.

It gets confusing when you use two different princples in your application.  You're using SOC in your domain, and you want to use DRY in your view.  That just doesn't work in many cases.  I have no idea why you are trying to decorate your View models with domain metadata attributes.  Obviously your view model is not the same as your domain model, so trying to use the domain metadata is going to result in an impedence mismatch.

That's not to say that you can't solve your problem.  You probably could, but it would require hacking around the basic design of MVC, adding your own extension pieces, etc.. The question is, how much work do you want to do to save yourself some work?

Comment: @ Mystere Man, thanks that makes sense. Yes, we want SOC and do not want the Domain model used directly(Model Binding) in the presentation layer . We also do not want to repeat validation in Domain layer and UI layer (Dry). 
The MetaDataType class can be used(Shared) in both the domain and the UI. What does not work is the Ivalidatable Object which must be implemented on either Domain or View Model. (Tried implementing on IValidatableObject but is ignored.)
So the next closest thing is to manually call the Validate method from the controller after model binding but that seems a little hokey.

Comment: @Andre - Like I said, you can probably get it to work by hacking around.  But in my opinion, you should have different validation code for view and domain, particlarly when your view model is not identical to your domain model.  I'm not sure how you can say your Metadata validation works, since you said your ViewModel contains several different objects combined.  That just doesn't make sense.

Comment: you are right, it only works for the trivial example where there is one domain model for the viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

May be following links have the answer you are looking for .(As question description is not very clear).

http://goneale.com/2009/03/04/using-metadatatype-attribute-with-aspnet-mvc-xval-validation-framework/

http://www.vladhorby.com/wpblog/2011/03/03/validator-validateobject-ignores-metadatatype-attributes/